# static method/function make call to non static function inside same class

Tags: php

I don't yet understand static and non static methods/functions (I will rather say method/function because i'm not so clear on the difference yet).

I'm building an extension (module) for my [boxbilling](http://www.boxbilling.com/) (BB) system and i'm kinda stuck.

This class can hook into BB's events and allow me to perform additional actions.

```
class Blah_Blah
{

   //The method/function that receives the event:    
    public static function onBeforeAdminCronRun(Box_Event $event)
    {
        startRun($event); //call "main" method/function to perform all my actions.
    }
```

I'm copying the coding style from another class that BB uses. So I ended up creating a main function with a couple of nested functions inside it.

```
public function startRun($event) // I believe that "public" exposes this method/function to the calling script, correct? if so, I can make private or remove "public"??
{
  // some parameter assignments and database calls goes here.
  // I will be calling the below methods/functions from here passing params where required.
  $someArray = array(); // I want this array to be accessible in the methods/functions below

  function firstFunction($params)
  {
    ...some code here...
    return;
  }
  function secondFunction()
  {
    ...some code here...
    loggingFunction('put this in log file');
    return;
  }
  function loggingFunction($msg)
  {
    // code to write $msg to a file
    // does not return a value
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to call

```
startRun($event)
```

inside

```
public static function onBeforeAdminCronRun(Box_Event $event)
```

?

What is the correct way to call the nested methods/functions inside

```
startRun($event)
```

?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go get some OOP terminology out of the way first: functions are static and methods are non-static (even though both are defined using the keyword `function` in PHP).  Static class members belong to the *class itself* and so there is only one global instance of them.  Non-static members belong to *instances of the class* and so each instance has its own copy of these non-static members<sup>1</sup>.

This means that you need an instance of the class -- called an object -- in order to use a non-static member.

In your case, `startRun()` does not appear to use any instance members of the object, so you could simply make it static to resolve the issue.

It's not clear in your case if you need to nest these functions inside of `startRun()` or if you should make them functions or methods of the class.  There can be valid cases for nesting functions, but with the limited information in your question it's difficult to say if this is one such case.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could make the argument that all instances share methods, and the object is simply passed to the method.  Under the hood this is exactly what is going on, but on a conceptual level each instance has "its own methods."  Think of instances sharing method implementations as an optimization.

Comment: Hi cdhowie and tnx for the response. So `public function startRun()` will become `public static function startRun()`? How do I make the call to this function (Function, because it's static now right?) from the first function? I understand that `$this->startRun()` wont work cause `$this` is not avail inside static functions. and how do I call my nested functions from the top level of the static function `startRun()`?

Comment: You would use `self::startRun()`.  The functions you define inside of the `startRun()` function can only be called within `startRun()`, because they are not visible outside of it.  Just call them like you would call any other function.  (Don't use `self::` because they are not class members; they are just regular functions that happen to have their scope limited to the `startRun()` function.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this and learning quite a lot (shot). I have followed your guidelines but ran into another snag... In the top level of my `startRun()` function I try to make a call to one of the nested functions (`function thelog($msg)`) but receive error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function thelog()"

Comment: @tSL You can't use a function before it is defined. Define the functions *first*, then try to call them.

Comment: I understand that the nested functions eg. `thelog($msg)` won't be "defined" until I call their parent function `startRun()`, so when my first static function `onBeforeAdminCronRun(Box_Event $event)` receives the event from my billing script, it calls the `startRun()` function, so I'm expecting it's nested functions to become "defined"...not so?

Comment: Ok, I've been wrecking my brain taking all your explanations into account and looked at some PHP manuals again - providing i'm understanding this correctly, a class should be instantiated by the "calling" script that is going to use it if the methods in the class are not "declared" as static, right? Else, if they are, the "calling" script does not have to instantiate the class and the script can just access the methods directly, right? In my case, if the "calling" script does not instantiate my class then it ONLY has access to "stuff" that is "declared" as static, right?

Comment: That said, taking into account that one of my static functions contains nested non static functions, shouldn't they be "automatically" accessible by that static function? I will understand if the other static function doesn't have access to them.

Comment: Right, without an instance of the class (`new Blah_Blah()`) you only have access to members that belong to the class (static) and you have no access to members that belong to instances (non-static).  Note that the nested functions cannot be static or non-static because they are not class members; they are simply regular functions with limited lexical scope.  If you are having trouble calling nested functions maybe pastebin the code and I'll have a look, or open another question.  (If you open a new question you might provide a link in a comment so I can find it.)

Comment: I have decided to move the nested functions outside of their static parent and made them all static, because I now believe that the "calling" script is not creating an instance of the class....I now have access to all my functions - Thank you very much for this learning curve, served me very well.